# XSL decimal formatting

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to pass a `xsl:value-of` to the
`format-number` function instead of a hardcoded number but I cannot get it to work. Is this
even possible? If so could someone point me to the right direction?

```
<Value>
   <xsl:value-of select='format-number(<xsl:value-of select="number"/>, "#.00")'/>
</Value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of format-number can be an xpath expression. 
Therefore try:

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(number, "#.00")'/>
```